# Cannot send email in localhost

Tags: php, email, if-statement, xampp, root

why i can't send email in localhost but when i try in hosting it can send email
this my code 
**

```
define('ROOT', 'localhost/OMG1/');
$kode = md5(uniqid(rand()));
$to = $_GET['f11'];
        $headers = "From: rizka.nugroho@omg-indonesia.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-to: $to\r\n";
        $pesan    = "Klik link berikut untuk verifikasi dan mengaktifkan akun : ";
        $pesan    .= ROOT."active.php?email=".$_GET['f11']."&kode=$kode&username=".$_GET['f5'];var_dump($pesan);
$a = @mail($to, "Aktivasi Akun Anda", $pesan, $headers);var_dump($a); 
if($a)
        {
            echo "Email send";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "failed to send mail";
        }
```

**
please help solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your email settings on XAMPP. A quick search on stack overflow shows that someone already asked a question like this and received and answer...

[How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Please try and use the search function first next time.

Comment: i have configure my php.ini and sendmail.ini, no error in my code but can't send email